# How to prevent Emacs from breaking hard links?

Tags: files

Let's say I have two files `file1` and `file2`:

```
$ echo aaa >file1
$ ln file1 file2
```

Then I check that the inodes are the same:

```
$ ls -i
18749779 file1  18749779 file2
```

which shows that the two files are actually the same. Now I edit `file1` in Emacs, and add a line with for example the text `bbb`, and save it and exit Emacs.

Now I get:

```
$ ls -i
18749781 file1  18749779 file2
$ cat file1
aaa
bbb
$ cat file2
aaa
```

So the hard link is broken. Note that this does not happen when I edit the file in `vim`, or if I simply do `echo bbb >>file1`..

How can I prevent Emacs from breaking hard links?

**Update:**

Note that I have

```
(require 'backup-dir)
(setq bkup-backup-directory-info
      '((t  "~/.emacs-backups/" ok-create full-path )))
```

in my `~/.emacs` init file. If I edit `file1` using `emacs -Q file1` instead, I get a file called `file1~` in the current directory that links to `file2` (has the same inode) but the `file1~` has not been modified (so it is identical to the old `file1`).. This is not what I desire. I would like both `file1` and `file2` to be the same file, and to include the updated file contents..

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution: If I add `(setq backup-by-copying t)` to my `~/.emacs` init file it works as desired..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Hakon solved his own problem with:

```
(setq backup-by-copying t)
```

If you prefer to retain the default behaviour, and use `back-up-by-copying` only for hard-linked files, you can use this instead (and leave `backup-by-copying` set to `nil`):

```
(setq backup-by-copying-when-linked t)
```

In addition, as pointed out by @Harald you can set `back-up-by-copying` as a file-local variable instead, to turn on this feature only for individual files.

The explanation of this behaviour from the Emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Copying.html):

> Backup files can be made by copying the old file or by renaming it. This makes a difference when the old file has multiple names (hard links). If the old file is renamed into the backup file, then the alternate names become names for the backup file. If the old file is copied instead, then the alternate names remain names for the file that you are editing, and the contents accessed by those names will be the new contents.

See the linked page for further discussion.

Comment: Note that you can set this as a file local variable, in case you don't want this behaviour for *all* files.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen noted!